# Undeclared Identifier After Import of Controller

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, import, uitableview

I want to update the color of a view called centerView based on an integer in a different view controller. So I imported the .h file of the controller where centerView was created and then wrote the code:

```
if (integer < 30){
    centerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
}
```

But it does not recognize what centerView is. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get a reference to your other viewController. You can't just call "centerView" if you haven't declared it or got it from somewhere. The most logical place to do this is in prepareForSegue:. There are many examples of exactly how to do this in these forums. Just do a search of prepareForSegue:. You would probably have something like:

```
SecondViewController *svc = [segue destinationViewController];

if (integer < 30){
    svc.centerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
}
```

assuming that centerView is a property on your Second ViewController.

Comment: But the view is not actually part of a ViewController it's actually part of a UITableViewCell

Comment: So you have a custom UITableViewCell class? Then you would need to reference your custom cell upon creation (cellForRowAtIndexPath:) to access the centerView. Its very hard to comment exactly unless you show more code or provide more description

Comment: Yes, I have a separate class. I just want to be able to change the color of the centerView, based on the integer in a different view controller.

Comment: Well that's very easy to do but it all depends on how you've set everything up. Where the other view controller is in the chain of views in your app will have an effect on how you would code it (passing the info forward or using delegation to send it back).